# Binary tree in concentric circles

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

Recently I came across a question in an interview "Print a complete binary tree in concentric circles".

```
        1
    2       3
  4   5   6   7
 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

The output should be

```
1 2 4 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 7 3
5 6
```

Could anyone help me out on how we can solve this problem?

Comment: Till you show what you've tried, and how it has not worked, it is just another "give me teh codez" question.

Comment: Hey it should be 6 5 and not 5 6.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can approach the problem. Arrange the tree by levels:

```
1
2, 3
4, 5, 6, 7
8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

So the data you have is `k` levels `L1, L2, ..., Lk`. Now answer this questions: After we execute one step, that is when one circle is traversed, how would the tree levels would look like after the traverse elements have been removed from the levels? How should I modify the levels and which elements should I print so that it would seems like I've traversed on circle?

In your example, after the first step the levels would be modified to just:

```
5, 6
```

So what was the operation that was executed?

After you've answered the questions just apply the same procedure couple of times until you've printed all elements.